# Compiling with Roslyn

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, roslyn

I'm trying to compile a solution but am getting an obscure error message when I try to save.

> Anonymous type <>__blahblah not completed

However in the source compiled there's no anonymous types whatsoever.

the code is

```
private static void Compile(ISolution solution)
    {
        var workspaceServices = (IHaveWorkspaceServices)solution;
        var projectDependencyService = workspaceServices.WorkspaceServices.GetService<IProjectDependencyService>();

        foreach (var projectId in projectDependencyService.GetDependencyGraph(solution).GetTopologicallySortedProjects())
        {
            var currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
            assemblyName.Name = "Most." + solution.GetProject(projectId).AssemblyName;

            var assemblyBuilder = currentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly
                           (assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

            var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.
                                            DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name);
            var types = moduleBuilder.GetTypes();
            types.Aggregate((ts, t) =>
            {
                var tb = t as TypeBuilder;
                return tb.CreateType();
            });
            solution.GetProject(projectId).GetCompilation().Emit(moduleBuilder);
            assemblyBuilder.Save(assemblyName.Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there anything actually called `blahblah` in your code? Or did you change the actual type name from the compiler message? It would be pretty hilarious if there's left over test code that prints 'blahblah' somewhere in Roslyn.

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken yeah that would have been fun but I did change it. it was more like '<>_AnnonymousType5'2`

Comment: This sounds like bug in Roslyn to me, you should probably report it.

Comment: @svick I would have hadn't it been for the fact that the submit bug on the Roslyn project page ends on a page letting me know that the page I was looking for doesn't exist

Comment: @RuneFS Go to https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx and click on the button under Microsoft Roslyn CTP.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Roslyn. It is reproduced in:

```
var assemblyName = new AssemblyName { Name = "Test" };

var compilation = Compilation.Create(
    assemblyName.Name, new CompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary),
    new[] {
        SyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
using System;
using System.Linq;    

public class C1
{
    public void M1() 
    {
        new[] {1}.Select(_ => new {});
    }
}")
    },
    new[] {
        MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("mscorlib"),
        MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System.Core")
    });

var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
    assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
var moduleBuilder = assembly.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name, assemblyName.Name + ".dll");

var emitResult = compilation.Emit(moduleBuilder);

if (emitResult.Success)
{
    assembly.Save(assemblyName.Name + ".dll"); //Error! Type '<>f__AnonymousType0' was not completed.
}
else
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: in your code there's an anonymous type so it might be a different error